# Jbang on cygwin shell

Tags: cygwin, quarkus

$ curl -Ls https://sh.jbang.dev | bash -s - app install --fresh --force quarkus@quarkusio
Downloading JBang...
Error downloading JBang

Comment: Hi arrow - sorry you are having issues with downloading Quarkus with JBang.

Any chance you are behind a proxy that could block downloads from github.com?

Comment: I just reproduced it. Not sure what happens but on Windows cygwin its failing. Can you use powershell or git bash as an alternative?


I opened https://github.com/jbangdev/jbang/issues/1223 as something to fix.

Comment: @MaxRydahlAndersen i get this:
[jbang] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/quarkus/quarkus-cli/2.6.3.Final/quarkus-cli-2.6.3.Final-runner.jar is not from a trusted source thus not running it automatically.

If you trust the url to be safe to run you can do one of the following:
0) Trust once: Add no trust, just run this time
1) Trust limited url in future:
    jbang trust add https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/quarkus/quarkus-cli/


Any other response will result in exit.

[jbang] Type in your choice (0 or 1) and hit enter. Times out after 10 seconds.

Comment: [jbang] [ERROR] Could not parse answer as a number. Aborting
[jbang] [ERROR] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/quarkus/quarkus-cli/2.6.3.Final/quarkus-cli-2.6.3.Final-runner.jar is not from a trusted source and user did not confirm trust thus aborting.
If you trust the url to be safe to run are here a few suggestions:
Limited trust:
     jbang trust add https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/quarkus/quarkus-cli/
Trust all subdomains:
    jbang trust add *.repo1.maven.org
Trust all sources (WARNING! disables url protection):
    jbang trust add *

Comment: For more control edit ~/.jbang/trusted-sources.json

[jbang] Run with --verbose for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jbang 0.88. Fixed the bug that made it fail on Cygwin shell.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem in Jbang download

```
$ curl -Ls https://sh.jbang.dev | bash -s - app install --fresh --force quarkus@quarkusio
Downloading JBang...
Installing JBang...
Downloading JDK 11. Be patient, this can take several minutes...
Installing JDK 11...
Fehler: Hauptklasse dev.jbang.Main konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
Ursache: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.jbang.Main
Fehler: Hauptklasse dev.jbang.Main konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
Ursache: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.jbang.Main
```

`konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden` means `could not be found or loaded`

but of course as there is no Cygwin Java Machine, I will be very surprised if could work...

Comment: what do you mean cygwin java machine ?

Proabably best to move this bug discussion to https://github.com/jbangdev/jbang/issues/1223